# Sorting String[] using Collections.reverseOrder()

Tags: java, arrays, collections

I need to sort a `String[]` with integer values in descending order. I am using String[] since the content of the array can either be a string or an integer.

To sort in descending order,

```
Arrays.sort(rows, Collections.reverseOrder());
```

where rows contain `"14","0","3"`;

Sorting works fine if string[] contain words.

I read that `Collections.reverseOrder()` doesn't work with primitive types, but will this fall under that category since am using `String[]` and not `int[]`?

If so, do we have a sorting mechanism other than using a for loop?

Comment: Are you saying the array contains both `String` and `Integer` instances (shouldn't be possible with a `String[]`), or that it contains strings *of* integers, e.g. `"14"`, `"0"`, `"3"`?

Comment: yes, the array contains string values of integers, "14","0","3"

Comment: And the issue is that they are not being sorted in the correct order?

Comment: What is your question? Are you aware that the string "1" is < than "19"? In other words, are you aware that numeric sort and lexicographic sort gives different results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The requirement is very specific and unusual, Of course, there is no standard method for it. But you could provide a custom comparator:

```
Arrays.sort(rows, new Comparator<String>()
{
    public int compare(String o1, String o2)
    {
         return Integer.parseInt(o2) - Integer.parseInt(o1);
    }
});
```

And you have to decide what to do if a string has unparsable integer and deal with the `NumberFormatException`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So I have used an if loop to see if the input string contains an integer or not and that being if(rows[0].matches("\\d+")){Arrays.sort(rows, new Comparator<String>()...}.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the natural order of strings is not the same as that of numbers: `"1" < "11" < "2"` as opposed to `1 < 2 < 11`.
It's a matter of writing your own comparator:

```
    Arrays.sort(rows, new Comparator<String>() {
        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
            return -(Integer.parseInt(o1) - Integer.parseInt(o2));
        }
    });
```

It will use the integer value of each string - it will crash if any of the strings isn't an integer -, and it will give the reverse order since it returns `-` the normal value. It is also inefficient because it parses every string in every comparison.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a sort in numeric order, you need a numeric type, not `String`. You can create an array of `Integer` and sort that.

Answer (score 0):

The sorting is done using alphabeticaly Strings. the String `"3"` is greater than `"14"` since 
the char `'3'` is greater than the char `'1'` (in reverse order).

you need either pass an own comparator witch converts the string to intergers before comparing them or have the intergers formatet so they have same number of digits and leading `0`.

If having words an number as String in the same array than you cant get the number to orderd numericaly.